# framework for chatting functionality that supports all mobile platforms and .net web application

Tags: iphone, android, asp.net, mobile, windows-mobile

our application is web integrated with mobile application.

develop web application in .net and mobile applications in iphone,android,blackberry,windows mobiles.

Now my requirement is i need to provide chat provision  between web application and mobile application.

i found xmpp framework but i don't know xmpp supports  in all mobile platforms.while i am checking xmpp does't support for iphone 3.0 simulator while i am executing the same framework it works with out any errors in iphone 4.0.

experts can any one suggest solution for my problem which is the most efficient framework that supports as my requirement.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean [groups.google.com/group/xmppframework](http://groups.google.com/group/xmppframework)

If most recent versions no longer support 3.0 you can go back to an older version which I know supported 3.0 (I used it to build a chat app for iPhone and Android), xmpp v2 perhaps. Or fix the lib to support 3.0 again, its a pretty simple library.

Answer (score 0):

Google Talk uses XMPP so any mobile device supporting Google Talk will work including:
Android, BlackBerry, iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for reply,In iphone 3.0 it is not working it gives errors....then what about web application